# Finding all irreducible polynomials in two variables, having (total) degree two.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296588/when-a-polynomial-in-two-variables-of-total-degree-three-is-irreducible/2296636#2296636) and getting a hint for a solution in the answer,
I wish to ask the following question:

> How to find all irreducible polynomials in two variables over $\mathbb{C}$, having (total) degree two?

A partial answer: Write $u=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$,
where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{C}$.

Then $u=ax^2+dx+ey+f$ is an example for an irreducible polynomial,
by a sufficient criterion which is brought in one of the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables).

**Remark:**
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/irreducible-polynomials-in-two-complex-variables) is relevant, and perhaps answers my current question. However, I prefer 'a pure algebraic' answer instead of an 'algebraic geometry' answer; is it true that considering partial derivatives of $u$ answers my question and how?

Comment: Why do you think there is an easier and more general answer than the one in [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa82/aa8237.pdf) you have cited?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the notions in that paper, so I only relied on the claim that appears in one of the answers in MO which says that a sufficient condition for irreducibility is being of the form $s(x)-t(y)$, with $s$ and $t$ having coprime degrees, so I thought that this only partially answers my question. (Is it true that theorem A in the paper you referred to contains a complete answer to my question?).

Comment: The answer you cited is correct and so one criterion as suggested there is, first homogenize your $u$ with a third variable $z$ and call it $U(x,y,z)$, so $u=U(x,y,1)$. Then $u$ is irreducible if and only if the three partial derivatives of $U$ have no non-trivial zeroes. Which, since these are linear, just says some $3\times 3$ matrix is non-singular.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! (Your comment may be considered as an answer). Is this method also works for more than two variables?

Comment: If I am not wrong, in the above notations, according to your claim: $u$ is irreducible if and only if $4acf-b^2f-ae^2-cd^2=f(4ac-b^2)-ae^2-cd^2$ is non-zero.

Comment: I guess that your claim also answers my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296588/when-a-polynomial-in-two-variables-of-total-degree-three-is-irreducible/2296636#comment4725274_2296636, but in this case the three partial derivatives are of degree two.

Comment: If $U$ is a homogeneous polynomial in a finite number ($>2$) of variables, and its partial derivatives have no common non-trivial zero, then $U$ is irreducible. Unfortunately, the converse holds only if the number of variables is three and degree is two.